# TensorFlow transfer learning ValueError

Tags: tensorflow, keras-layer, transfer-learning, tensorflow-hub, mobilenet

I was trying transfer learning, on an image classification problem, on google colab and when I ran this code:

```
# Setup input shape to the model
INPUT_SHAPE = [None, 244, 244, 3] # batch, height, width, colour channels

# Setup output shape of the model
OUTPUT_SHAPE = 120

# Setup model URL form TensorFlow Hub
MODEL_URL =  "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_130_224/classification/4"

# Create a function which builds a Keras model
def create_model(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, output_shape=OUTPUT_SHAPE, model_url=MODEL_URL):
  print("Building model with:", MODEL_URL)

  # Setup the model layers
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(MODEL_URL), # Layer 1 (input layer)
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=OUTPUT_SHAPE,
                          activation="softmax") # Layer 2 (output layer)
  ])

  # Compile the model
  model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
      metrics=["accuracy"]
  )

  # Build the model
  model.build(INPUT_SHAPE)

  return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

I got this error:

```
Building model with: https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_130_224/classification/4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-0fd4f47c95c0> in <module>()
----> 1 model = create_model()
      2 model.summary()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    263       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    264         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 265           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    266         else:
    267           raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py:229 call  *
        result = smart_cond.smart_cond(training,
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py:486 _call_attribute  **
        return instance.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:580 __call__
        result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:627 _call
        self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:506 _initialize
        *args, **kwds))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:2446 _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
        graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:2777 _maybe_define_function
        graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:2667 _create_graph_function
        capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:981 func_graph_from_py_func
        func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:441 wrapped_fn
        return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/function_deserialization.py:261 restored_function_body
        "\n\n".join(signature_descriptions)))

    ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 244, 244, 3), dtype=float32)
        * False
        * False
        * 0.99
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * False
        * True
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * True
        * False
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 3:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * True
        * True
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 4:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * False
        * False
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

I tried installing tf-nightly and older versions of tensorflow to see if it would run, but that did not work. I also tried an older version of tensorflow_hub and that too caused some more errors. I tried to factory reset the notebook and try again, and i get the same error. The error doesn't show up if I comment out `model.build(INPUT_SHAPE)` . Other than that I'm not sure what to do to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes are needed for your code to work.

1. We should use [MobileNet_V2_Feature_Vector](http://%22https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4%22) Module instead of [MobileNet_V2_Image_Classification](http://%22https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_130_224/classification/4%22) Module, as you want to use MobileNet for **your Dataset**, rather than using it on `ImageNet Dataset`.
2. While using [MobileNet_V2_Feature_Vector](http://%22https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4%22) Module, we should use an `Input Layer` as shown below:

```
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(224,224,3))
```

Complete working code is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

# Setup input shape to the model
INPUT_SHAPE = [None, 244, 244, 3] # batch, height, width, colour channels

# Setup output shape of the model
OUTPUT_SHAPE = 120

# Setup model URL form TensorFlow Hub
MODEL_URL =  "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4"

# Create a function which builds a Keras model
def create_model(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, output_shape=OUTPUT_SHAPE, model_url=MODEL_URL):
  print("Building model with:", MODEL_URL)

  # Setup the model layers
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(224,224,3)),
    hub.KerasLayer(MODEL_URL, output_shape=[1280],
                   trainable=False), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=OUTPUT_SHAPE,
                          activation="softmax")
  ])

  # Compile the model
  model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
      metrics=["accuracy"]
  )

  # Build the model
  model.build(INPUT_SHAPE)

  return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
Building model with: https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
keras_layer_8 (KerasLayer)   (None, 1280)              2257984   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 120)               153720    
=================================================================
Total params: 2,411,704
Trainable params: 153,720
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
```

Please refer this comprehensive [TF Hub Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_image_retraining#introduction) for more details on using `MobileNet_V2` for your `Dataset`.